# Closing all the open activities when `uncaughtException` called

Tags: android, unhandled-exception, uncaught-exception

What I want to do is, close all the open activities when there is any unhandled exception.
I have a `BaseActivity` which is base for all the activities in my application and every activity derived from this class.
I have called `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in `onCreate` of `BaseActivity`.

I have a `BaseActivity` as below:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Exceptions that are not handled are received in GlobalExceptionHandler class              
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());
    }

    public class MyExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler 
    {  
        @Override  
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) 
        {
            String report = "";

            // Code to generate report string
            ......
            // Code to generate report string

            // Start error screen 
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ErrorScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("error", report);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            // Exit
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is my ErrorScreen Activity:

```
public class ErrorScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.error_screen_layout);

        // Display error report from intent
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn_exit_app:
            {
                // All this is not working
                // and few activities are still there 
                finish();

                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

                System.exit(1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

On any unhandeled exception, my `uncaughtException` function is getting called which is as expected, then i start new activity for displaying error details and a button to exit in `ErrroScreen` activity.

But problem is that, after selecting exit app button, not all the activities in the application are closing, there are still few activities that are open, how to close all the open activities?

Answer (score 1):

```
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler androidDefaultUEH;

private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        //mInstance.startActivity(new Intent(mInstance, HomeActivity.class));
        Log.e("TestApplication", "Uncaught exception is: ", ex);
        // here I do logging of exception to a db
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong..... TimesNow App is restarting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        PendingIntent myActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                192837, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ToBeOpenedActivity.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager;
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                15000, myActivity);
        System.exit(0);

        androidDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
};
```

Write this method in your application class..

Comment: But I don't want to auto restart my application after 15000 ms, also I don't want to display just a Toast. i just want to close all the open activities. thats it.

Comment: means u wanna close app??

Comment: yes i just want to display error information and when user selects exit app button i want to close the app completely.